# Is there any difference in meaning between "give" and "give away"?

Tags: difference, verbs, phrasal-verbs

Is there any difference in meaning between *give* and *give away*. For example:

> The old man **gave** all his money to the people in need.
>
> The old man **gave away** all his money to the people in need.

I am not a native English speaker, but it feels like the second sentence means that the man didn't need the money or that the money isn't such a big deal for him, so he decided to get rid of them. Tell me please if am at all right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a subtle difference, although in the examples you cite, there is really no difference in meaning:

> The old man gave all **his** money to the people in need.
>
> The old man gave away all **his** money to the people in need.

Usually "*give away*" means that you give someone something that *is yours* - for example, you would not usually say this about a gift that you had specifically bought someone, because you never intended to keep it for yourself. In your examples, both statements make it clear that the old man's money was **his**, so there is no difference in meaning.

Also, "give away" tends to imply that you the item(s) have gone far from your sight. I would not use "give away" if, for example, I gave a possession of mine to my children, because the item is still within my family. I would just that "I gave it to my child"; if I gave the item to someone beyond my family circle then I would say that "I gave it away".